# How to mock for custom Event?

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

```
MyEvent extends EventObject.

public class MyEvent extends EventObject {
    private int buttonName;


    public void setNum( int num) {
        this.num= num;
    }

    public int getNum(){
        return num;
    }


    public MyEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }
}
```

With mockito-all-2.0.2-beta, I do mock the above Event for a unit test

```
import org.junit.After;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotEquals;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;


public class MyEventTest {

    public MyEventTest() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of getButtonNum method, of class MyEvent.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetButtonNumEqual() {
        System.out.println("setButtonNum");      
        MyEvent evt = mock(MyEvent.class);
        int buttonNum = 1;         
        evt.setButtonNum(buttonNum);
        int result = evt.getButtonNum();
        System.out.println(buttonNum);
        System.out.println(result);
        assertEquals(buttonNum, result);     
    }

    /**
     * Test of getButtonNum method, of class MyEvent.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetButtonNumNotEqual() {
        System.out.println("setButtonNum");      
        MyEvent evt = mock(MyEvent.class);
        int buttonNum = 2;
        int notEqualNum = 1;
        evt.setButtonNum(buttonNum);
        int result = evt.getButtonNum();
        System.out.println(buttonNum);
        System.out.println(result);
        assertNotEquals(notEqualNum, result);     
    }

}
```

First Test is failed and Second Test is passed. The print output is below.
    {
    setButtonNum
    1
    0
and
    setButtonNum
    2
    0
    }
I would like to know why the first test is fail and how to do unit test a custom event.

Please, let me know what mistake I did. I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: 1. You are not defining expected return value for `evt.getButtonNum()` when calling it.  2. You dont mock class that your are unit testing. Usually you mock dependencies that your testing class is using. Check example like this on how to use mocking: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-behavior

Comment: According your advice, I misused the mock(). I would rather use it on a event listener. Thank you for your explanation and link.